# pyenv in fish: Unknown command: pyenv

Tags: fish, pyenv

When I started my fish shell today I got following error:

```
fish: Unknown command: pyenv
~/.config/fish/conf.d/pyenv.fish (line 3): 
pyenv init --path | source
^
from sourcing file ~/.config/fish/conf.d/pyenv.fish
    called on line 253 of file /usr/local/Cellar/fish/3.3.1/share/fish/config.fish
from sourcing file /usr/local/Cellar/fish/3.3.1/share/fish/config.fish
    called during startup
fish: Unknown command: pyenv
~/.config/fish/conf.d/pyenv.fish (line 4): 
pyenv init - | source
^
from sourcing file ~/.config/fish/conf.d/pyenv.fish
    called on line 253 of file /usr/local/Cellar/fish/3.3.1/share/fish/config.fish
from sourcing file /usr/local/Cellar/fish/3.3.1/share/fish/config.fish
    called during startup
```

I never had it before so I think it's due to a pyenv update?

My pyenv.fish file is as follows:

```
set -x PATH ~/.pyenv/bin $PATH

pyenv init --path | source
pyenv init - | source
```

Anyone has an idea how to solve this? I did not find any solution via google.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This error means that fish can't find a thing called `pyenv` to execute.

Most likely that means that there is no file called `pyenv` in ~/.pyenv/bin, or it's not executable.

So it appears you broke your pyenv installation or haven't installed it yet (e.g. on a new machine).

Comment: Thanks, this led me to the solution which was running: 
curl https://pyenv.run | bash

Comment: This happens to me, yet it runs perfectly fine in ZSH

Comment: That means your $PATH isn't set up the same in both shells.